# Not able to add a state prop in a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add dynamically an id into  tag

`<a href="/profile?id="{this.state.userInfo.id}>`

it's not working. VS code keep saying that I have to add `...`

Any idea ? Sorry I am newby in JavaScript and React.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you try to render link like `/profile?id=123`, where `123` is userId, then you should use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to insert variable value to your string.

```
<a href={`/profile?id=${this.state.userInfo.id}`}>
```

Now expression in braces would be interpreted and transformed into string with variable value.

But, if you need to make working link with `react-router`, you need to use `Link` from `react-router-dom`. You can find examples [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string template literal.

```
<a href={`/profile?id=${this.state.userInfo.id}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

In react we dont user the  tag for routing insted we use a package/library called react-router-dom  for handling routing. You can go throught the documentaion as ther are may ways for dynamic routing in React. Hope this helps. As the  tag refreshes the page a may have an unlikely behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `<Link>` instead of `<a>` using **react-router-dom**

**this sample is from their website**

````
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
             </nav>
       </Router>```
````